# Add Class Based on Style Attribute

Tags: jquery, html, css

The CMS I'm using doesn't seem to apply a class name if the element is floated left or right. I was hoping to not have to mess with the TinyMCE code stuff, and instead do this with jQuery.

Right now, when I align an image to the left or right, it will add the styles inline with the image like so:

```
<img src="image.jpg" style="float:left">
```

I was hoping that for those elements that have that style applied, I could add a class name of "alignleft". I tried this, but it does not work:

```
$( 'a[ style=' + 'float: left;' + ']' ).addClass( 'alignleft' );
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I don't know why you're concatenating one string with another instead of just writing the string in the first place `'a[ style=float: left;]'`

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest selecting the possible elements that might be `float: left` and then filtering to find those that *are*, and adding the class-name of `alignleft` to those:

```
$('a, img').filter(function(){
    return this.style.float === 'left';
}).addClass('alignleft');
```

This approach avoids the requirement that the `style` attribute must *begin* with the, and be *exactly*, `style="float: left;"`, including the precise white-space.

Of course, this approach does require that the `float: left` is assigned in the inline `style` attribute; if there's a chance that it might be assigned in a stylesheet, whether external or in the `head` of the page, then you'd have to use jQuery's `css()` method (which can call `getComputedStyle()` or `currentStyle()` to parse those stylesheets (unless you want to do so yourself), leading to:

```
$('a, img').filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('float') === 'left';
}).addClass('alignleft');
```

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: Great in theory but this.float is undefined.

Comment: "This approach avoids the requirement that the style attribute must begin with the, and be exactly, style="float: left;", including the precise white-space." <- what about using `~=` instead of `=` then?

Comment: @ant: that would work, certainly, but I'm not sure what the benefit would be? The above approaches avoid parsing the string of the `style` attribute, which seems/feels better to me. I Can't offer any evidence that it's any *faster*, or actually *better*, but it's how I prefer to do it is all.

Comment: @antindexer: ~= would still not match if there aren't any whitespaces. you have to use a combined version of the attribute selector i would suggest. See popnoodles answer, I added a second code example.

Comment: @MarkusKottländer if yu see my answer I provide link about selectors so it is just food for brain. I hope other part can be distinguished by the person who asks question.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put double quotation mark after `=` sign and and before closing `]` symbol. And `style~=` should be used instead of `=` sign. This means style attribute contains float:left string.

```
$( 'a[ style~="' + 'float: left;' + '"]' ).addClass( 'alignleft' );
```

Here is working example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CTB4E/).

**For them who concern:**

if you considering the `float: left` or `float:left` can not be distinguished by attribute selector. Watch this:

```
$( 'a[style*="' + 'float:left' + '"], a[style*="' + 'float: left' + '"]' ).addClass( 'alignleft' );
```

This will work for everything with space or with out the space. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CTB4E/1/) if your are short of understanding what I want to explain here. Of course some developers with curvehands.dll installed can say that it will not work for more then one space in attribute parameter. Can consider to use what ever they like and give answer as they whanted.

**EDIT.**
Read more about selectors [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: This won't work. The style attribute is `float:left` which will not be caught in that selector.

Comment: But why are you concatenating two strings? I know that's how the OP wrote it, but...it still doesn't make *sense*, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: First of all it is given example by OP. And in future 'float: left;' will be changed string variable I guess.

Comment: to @popnoodles it can be used by `*=` selector then. The person who asked question should read reference which I provide about selectors.

Comment: The element's style attribute has no space and no semicolon. *= isn't going to find `float: left;`. But I covered that in my answer (which I deleted as David's is the most appropriate and most robust solution).

Comment: You know the solution given by us should be more than one. Decision should be taken by OP. Not you and me. I am not telling and pretending my answer is the best. Using filter or each or other for loop is may be better.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img[style*="float"][style*="left"]').addClass('alignleft');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rzp79/

**EDIT** Well ok, you can't use it if you also have a `border-left` for example.

Comment: This will not do the trick. Just consider this case `float:right` and `align:left`. Does it make sense?